# Azure Nested Virtualization - seamless access to guest VMs

Tags: azure, nested, virtualization

I successfully set up nested virtualization in Azure. Using NAT port forwarding, I can RDP to the guest VMs without any issue. For us, this is not a complete solution as we need to access the guest machine (just on the internal network) by **machine name** not just through a unique port for each machine. For example, if I have a guest VM called guest1, I should be able to launch explorer and go directly to \guest1\c$ (from not just the host, but from outside the host as well) just as would able to if guest1 were a non-nested VM. All we can do right now is RDP to guest1, that too through a unique port, so guest1:port1 for guest1 and guest2:port2 for guest2.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

PS: I followed the instructions here (very useful): https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2017/07/how-to-setup-nested-virtualization-in-microsoft-azure/

Comment: how do you call nested virtualization on azure a solution. why would you use it in any solution? its not supposed to be anything real anyway

Comment: Not supposed to be real? I don't follow? Why did MSFT even implement this feature if it does not serve any purpose?

Comment: well, for hyper-v containers, mostly. i doubt MS recommends nested virtualization on azure for anything production grade. notice how [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/) announcement talks about dev\test\training scenarios only

Comment: Our guest VMs are for test/development and used mostly for CI/CD staging before moving to production . We ventured into nested VMs mainly to save costs.